# Database Changes

Tags: ms-access

I have a situation where I have the 2 copies of a same MS Access DB. In one Db some modifications has been done like , in some tables some new rows has been inserted , some existing rows has been modified.
 Now the trick is that i have to identify that in which tables , which rows the modification has been made (in case of any modification done in any existing row) or what are the new rows that have been inserted and in which tables. All these comparysion has to be done against the 2nd copy of that database (before all the modifications).

CAn any one help me out in this? I

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Visual Studio, the database edition has schema and data compare functionality that is made for just this sort of problems.

Comment: I am actualy priviledged with VB 6 only.